# Mac Catalyst toolbar increases in height with .principal placement

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, swiftui-navigationview, mac-catalyst

I am developing a SwiftUI Mac Catalyst app with a simple NavigationView and a toolbar.

As soon as I give my toolbarItem the `.principal` placement the toolbar increases in height (nearly doubles). In the image you can see the large space between "MyButton" and the border of the view.

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Sidebar")
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello, world!")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
            .border(.red)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
                    Button {
                        toggle.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("MyButton")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the placement of my toolbarItem is `.automatic`, `.navigation`, etc., the height is normal again.

I have been searching for a solution for that problem for a long time now. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

(had the same problem and found your question before i found the answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).